# Google /geolocation/v1/geolocate api

Tags: google-api, geolocation

How can I use Google/geolocation/v1/geolocate API to get the client's latitude and longitude to get the lat and longitude from IP-address? which is to be called from the server?
Also, need to get the IP from the X-Forwaded-For header

request:
{
"considerIp": true,
}